# mongoose - Cast 'parent' type to 'child' type based on discriminator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So I have a base schema called `Base` and using `Base.discriminator(...)` I have created sub-types called `ChildA` and `ChildB`.

If I do `Base.find({})` I will get all documents, is it possible to cast an instance of `Base` to `ChildA` or `ChildB` depending on the discriminator value?